# When refreshing access token early, is old access token still valid?

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token, refresh-token

In OAuth2, If I choose to preemptively refresh the access token, does the old access token maintain validity until the original expiration date? Or does it get wiped earlier and replaced by the new?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on the type of token and the implementation of the Authorization Server. When the access token is a JWT and validation is done locally at the Resource Server the old token would remain valid. When the access token is a "reference" token that needs to validated against the Authorization Server, then the Authorization Server may have revoked the old access token when it issued the new one and the old one won't validate anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The old access token will remain alive until unless it meets its expiry date even though the access token has been refreshed.